# Derivative of a Vector with respect to its norm (special relativity)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, vectors

I came across an equation (related to special relativity) that requires me to to take a derivative of a vector with respect to to it's own norm. In a bit more detail, what I mean is, let:

$$\vec T(\tau) = \{T_1(\tau), T_2(\tau), \dotsb, T_t(\tau)\}$$
$$\vec X(\tau) = \{X_1(\tau), X_2(\tau), \dotsb, X_x(\tau)\}$$
With $\vec T$ and $\vec X$ having dimensions $t$ and $x$ respectively and both being vector functions of $\tau$.

Also let:

$$\tau^2 = w^2 - s^2 = \vec T \cdot \vec T - \vec X \cdot \vec X$$

Where:

$$w = \lVert \vec T \rVert \qquad s = \lVert \vec X \rVert$$

Knowing that:
$$d\tau^2 = dw^2 - ds^2= d\vec T \cdot d\vec T - d\vec X \cdot d\vec X$$

How then, can take the derivative $\frac {d\vec T}{dw}$?

It may be useful to know that $d\vec X = [\beta]\cdot d\vec T$, where $[\beta]$ is a constant matrix of dimension $x\times t$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'll trade your question for an easier one, perhaps my thoughts on this two-dimensional problem may give you some ideas. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with time-space coordinates $(t,x)$ and the metric $\eta = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]$. Note the interval $I((t_1,x_1),(t_2,x_2)) = (t_2-t_1)^2-(x_2-x_1)^2$ can be compactly expressed as $I(v,w) = (w-v)^T\eta (w-v)$. Getting back to the main point here, note the "norm" of $v=(v_1,v_2)$ is given by
$$ |v| = \sqrt{|I(v,v)|}  = \sqrt{|v_1^2-v_2^2|}. $$
Why the quotes? Well, as there are vectors like $(1,1)$ which are nonzero and yet have "norm" zero we should probably call it a pseudo-norm. That said, differentiation with respect to $|v|$ probably should be understood in terms of a choice of coordinates for which the psuedo-norm is one of the coordinates. The natural second choice in this hyperbolic context is that of the hyperbolic angle (rapidity in physics). In particular, define: $r \geq 0$ and
$$ x = r\cosh(\phi) \qquad \& \qquad y = r\sinh(\phi) $$
This suggests relations $x^2-y^2=r^2$ and $\tanh(\phi) = y/x$. Now, these coordinates are tricky, the formulas above only apply to $x,y >0$. To extend to other quadrants similar formulas can be written. Let's focus on quadrant I where the formulas given are reasonable. To convert a partial derivative with respect to $r$ into $x,y$ derivatives the standard technique is the chain rule:
$$ \partial_r=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \cosh(\phi) \partial_x + \sinh(\phi) \partial_y$$
I suppose that is a partial answer to your post, but I'll continue for a bit to show a bit more about this approach. We can also relate $\partial_{\phi}$ to the Cartesian coordinate derivations:
$$ \partial_{\phi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = r\sinh(\phi) \partial_x + r\cosh(\phi) \partial_y$$
Consider, the psuedo-Laplacian 
$$ \partial_x^2-\partial_y^2= (\partial_x+\partial_y)(\partial_x-\partial_y)$$
A short calculation shows $\partial_x = \cosh (\phi) \partial_r-\frac{1}{r}\sinh(\phi)\partial_{\phi}$ and $\partial_y = -\sinh (\phi) \partial_r+\frac{1}{r}\cosh(\phi)\partial_{\phi}$. Note $\cosh(\phi) \pm \sinh(\phi) =e^{\pm \phi}$. This gives
$$ \partial_x^2-\partial_y^2= e^{-\phi}\left(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r}\partial_{\phi}\right)\left[ e^{\phi}\left(\partial_r-\frac{1}{r}\partial_{\phi} \right) \right] $$
I suppose this could be simplified some, but, I expect there will be a mixed derivative term. This is similar to the problem of writing the Laplacian in polar coordinates. There is a mixed-derivative term in that problem. Also, it seems to me that is similar to your question in the sense that differentiation with respect to the polar radius is in a sense differentiation with respect to the Euclidean norm. Similar comments apply to spherical coordinates and differentiation with respect to $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Differentiation in curvelinear coordinates required some care. I hope this gives you some ideas about what perhaps you should do...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with the concepts you displayed, as they are related to the usual (3,1) Minkowski Space used in the Special theory of Relativity. My issue comes in because I'm trying to apply these rules in a higher "time-dimensional" Specetime, meaning a spacetime with more than one timelike dimensions. Like (3,2) or (4,3). So time stops being a scalar t, and becomes a vector (t_1, t_2, ...). And in doing the math, I come across the derivative dT/dw, where w is the norm of T. This is what I cannot seem to be able to solve.

Comment: @Disousa right, so I would assume you should find a system of coordinates in which one of the coordinates is the norm of the point identified as a vector from the origin. This would seem natural. To group several time together just use something like $t_1=r\cos(u)\cosh(\phi)$ and $t_2=r\sin(u)\cosh(\phi)$ then $t_1^2+t_2^2 = r^2\cosh^2(\phi)$ so if you arrange the sum of the squares of coordinates of the spatial part to work out to $r^2 \sinh^2(\phi)$ then the difference of the time and space squares will work out to $r^2$ which is connected to $\partial/\partial r$ (your desired calculation).

Comment: I think I got it. Didn't think of grouping time like that. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help, I think you've now increased the amount of time I've spent thinking about higher dimensional time by at least a factor of 10 :)